# Why isn't Postgres using the index with Distinct?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.prodhistory (
  curve_id           int4 NOT NULL,
  start_prod_date    date NOT NULL,
  prod_date          date NOT NULL,
  monthly_prod_rate  float4 NOT NULL,
  eff_date           timestamp NOT NULL,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT prodhistorypk
    PRIMARY KEY (curve_id, prod_date, start_prod_date, eff_date),
  /* Foreign keys */
  CONSTRAINT prodhistory2typecurves_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (curve_id)
    REFERENCES public.typecurves(curve_id)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );

CREATE INDEX prodhistory_idx_curve_id01
  ON public.prodhistory
  (curve_id);
```

with ~42M rows.

And I execute this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT curve_id FROM prodhistory
```

Which I expect would be very quick, given the index.  But no, 270 secs.  So I explain, and I get:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=824870.03..824873.08 rows=305 width=4) (actual time=211834.018..211834.097 rows=315 loops=1)   
  Output: curve_id  
  Group Key: prodhistory.curve_id   
  ->  Seq Scan on public.prodhistory  (cost=0.00..718003.22 rows=42746722 width=4) (actual time=12.751..200826.299 rows=43218808 loops=1)   
        Output: curve_id    
Planning time: 0.115 ms 
Execution time: 211848.137 ms
```

I'm not to experienced in reading these plans, but a Seq Scan on the DB seems bad.

Any thoughts?  I'm sort of stumped.

Comment: I mean, how many distinct values are there for `curve_id`?. Also, what's the point of making the PK the whole table?

Comment: Show us the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)`.

Comment: @lamak - there are currently 300 distinct values, and probably will end up with close to 1000.  Also, the PK is so that I can version each row - the data gets updated monthly, but only the recent data (last two years of "prod_date") gets updated.  And the PK defines what is unique in the table, per good practice.

Comment: The index contains all table's columns - it is just a copy of the whole table. Why do you think that scanning of the index should be faster than scanning of the table in this case ? The index and the table contain the same data, their size on the disk is the same. Create an index on `curve_id` column alone.

Comment: Vacuum analyze prodhistory reports nothing and does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

This plan is chosen because PostgreSQL thinks it is cheaper.

You can compare by setting

```
SET enable_seqscan=off;
```

and then re-running your `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` statement. Compare `cost` and `actual time` in both cases and check if PostgreSQL estimated correctly or not.

If you find that using an `Index Scan` or `Index Only Scan` is actually cheaper, you could consider twiddling the cost parameters to match your machine better, e.g. lower `random_page_cost` or `cpu_index_tuple_cost` or raise `cpu_tuple_cost`.

Comment: Using `SET enable_seqscan=off;` DOES change the query plan to  `Index Only Scan`, but still there is no benefit from having many duplicate values. The number scanned rows is still much higher than the number returned rows. I would expect postgres to be smart enough to jump to the next distinct value, instead of scanning them all.

Comment: PostgreSQL cannot do that. Even if it could, it would only be a benefit if there are few distinct values, because a sequential scan is usually faster than random access.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL "index only scans" aren't always as cheap as you might think.

The reason is that each row needs to be checked as to whether it is visible to the MVCC snapshot or not.

Whether this is cheap or not depends on the table's visibility map.

If you force an index only scan (as per laurenz-albe's answer):

```
SET enable_seqscan=off;
```

Then run your query with:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ON, BUFFERS ON)
```

You may see query plan output with "heap fetches" as below. This means that the table's actual row data is being accessed, not just the index.

```
Index Only Scan using my_index on my_table  (cost=0.42..17792.01 rows=595195 width=20) (actual time=37.942..2330.737 rows=539105 loops=1)
    Heap Fetches: 234180
```

The official documentation describes this here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html

You may be able to resolve this by altering the way the table is updated, or by adjusting your auto vacuum settings.